# How to communicate with the reader using PC/SC

Tags: pcsc

I'm trying to communicate with an ACS ACR122U NFC card reader using the PC/SC API on Windows (winscard.dll).

According to [this document](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf), there is a pseudo-APDU available to read the card reader firmware version: `FF 00 48 00 00`

With a card in the reader, I have this working: I call `SCardEstablishContext()`, then `SCardConnectA()` to get a handle, then with the handle I call `SCardTransmit()`. I get an answer, just as expected.

But how to do that without a card in the reader?

The above document says:

> • Pseudo-APDUs can be sent through the “ACR122U PICC Interface” if the tag is already connected
>   • Pseudo-APDUs can be sent using “Escape Command” if the tag is not yet presented

I have no idea what that means. If I try the same method as above without a card in the reader, the `SCardConnectA()` call fails with an `SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD` error, which means I have no handle to call `SCardTransmit()` with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. To be allowed to call [`SCardConnectA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardconnecta) without a card in the reader, `dwShareMode` must be `SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT` **and** `dwPreferredProtocols` must be `0`.

Comment: There is this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/35389657/1110642 With an alternate solution as well.

Comment: That's the *same* solution, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, yes it is. `SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED` equals to 0.