# PCSC C# Load Authenctication Keys without smart card

Tags: c#, mifare, apdu, pcsc

I have a ACR1281 reader. I'm trying to load authentication keys on the reader without a card.

When I write:

```
var isoReader = new IsoReader(
    context, readerName, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any, false)
```

it returns me a "Removed Card" error.

But if I use `SCardShareMode.Direct`, I can't transmit `apdu-commands` to load authentication keys.

Can I work with the reader without a card? Which mode and protocol do I need?

Comment: You are not the only one experiencing this issue. For me it seems like a bug in the windows PC/SC implementation since in the Linux PCSCLite implementation it works.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539775/sending-apdu-with-winscard-dll-pc-sc-without-a-smart-card-connected), try to set `SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED` as protocol parameter. So inside the smartcard framework you are using there should be something like `SCardProtocol.Undefined`.